# Sed command to remove everything following the colon

Tags: regex, sed

I have the collection of text files containing/not the phrase (B core file).

Then I tried this:

```
sudo find / -type f -name core | xargs file | grep 'B core file' | sed 's/:ELF.*//g' | xargs rm -f
```

To **remove specific files with the phrase "B core file"**.

But that command won't work.

I'm hoping for the solution.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Only the find command will be run with root permissions. The rm will be run with your user id and because of this will fail. Put the whole command in a script and run the script with sudo.

You can also use an extra sudo for each command, which access the files, which are probably not readable or writable for you:

```
sudo find / -type f -name core | xargs sudo file | sudo grep 'B core file' | sed 's/:ELF.*//g' | xargs sudo rm -f
```

Comment: Thank ceving. I'll give it a try.
However, could you confirm that the regex 's/:ELF.*//g' is proper. I don't what ELF is stand for?

Comment: I tried:
sudo find / -type f -name core | xargs file | grep 'B core file' | sed 's/:.*//g' | xargs rm -f. The regex ':.*' is to replace all chars following the colons which will then give me the path of the file only, but I still don't get it fully ( because ':*' didn't work).
In my case, it's not permission issue. because the file was found is created by me.

Answer (score 0):

That looks overly complicated.

try:

grep -l 'B core file' * | xargs rm

It will remove files containing 'B core file' from the directory you're standing in when running this.

Comment: Hi Mikael,

I was about extract the path of filtered files based on file type, not the content of the files.
Regards,

Comment: Oh ok. Your question and title isn't very clear.